# What are the pros and cons of using d-pointers?

Tags: c++, qt, pimpl-idiom

d-pointers are heavily used in Qt, they are an implementation of pimpl idiom. I know advantages and disadvantages of pimpl idiom. But I have missed the advantages of d-pointers implementation. [Here](http://zchydem.enume.net/2010/01/19/qt-howto-private-classes-and-d-pointers/) and [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Private_implementation) are the samples of d-pointers. 
Isn't it easier to just use this?

```
class MyClassPrivate;
class MyClass {
  // interface methods
private:
  MyClassPrivate *pimpl_;
};
```

Comment: Are there really any differences between "just pimpl" and d-pointers? Except for relying on macros to automate the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of macros for d-pointer pattern provides some sort convenience and consistencies. For example, Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE ensures that the pimpl private class for Foo is named as FooPrivate, that FooPrivate befriends Foo, and creates an nice inline function (both const and nonconst versions) called d_func(). The latter is used in Q_D macro, which basically creates a scoped/local variable d which points to the private class instance.

In short, you need not use Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE and other macros, but doing so will make the code shorter, cleaner, and consistent.

Answer (score 18):

d-pointers are one implementation, among many, of the pimpl pattern. It is also one of the early implementations: "*The name 'd-pointer' stems from Trolltech's Arnt Gulbrandsen, who first introduced the technique into Qt, making it one of the first C++ GUI libraries to maintain binary compatibility even between bigger release.*" [Source](http://caole.net/diary/d_pointer.html)

One advantage of using macros is the option of changing some implementation details of the pattern implementation in a central place at compile time. You could for example design your macros to leave you the option of switching to the [fast pimpl implementation](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm) at a later time without changing tons of code (hopefully you won't need this if you are using pimpl :-)). Provided that you made no mistakes in your macro design/implementation...

However, I would personally recommend avoiding macros for your pimpl implementation as they are cryptic for any newcomer to your source tree. Macros create magical dialects that are often error-prone and not as meaningful as the original source code. They also come with all the problems associated with the C Pre Processor; it's unaware of the underlying language.

Personally I like to use what I call a d-reference. Instead of a pointer, you use a reference and you don't have to d-reference. 8-) It looks something like this:

```
// MyClass.h

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    // implementation methods

private:
    class MyClassPrivate& d;
};

// MyClass.cpp

struct MyClassPrivate
{
    int x;
};

MyClass::MyClass()
: d(*new MyClassPrivate)
{

}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    delete &d;
}

// In methods use d.x
```

Comment: first link is 404

Answer (score 0):

I think that d-pointers are really just a few handy macros for implementing the *pimpl* idiom. Just take a look at the definition of all these macros: `Q_D`, `Q_Q`, `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE`, etc. They are just shortcuts for parts of *pimpl*. For example most of the time you want to keep the reference to the original class in the private class. There are `Q_Q` and `Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC` for this. After all, using the macros forces all the team to have a uniform implementation of *pimpl*. Otherwise some people would call the private pointer `d`, others `pimpl_`, imagine this mess.