# Pros and Cons of usage of reference in case of PIMPL idiom

Tags: c++, design-patterns

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983972/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-d-pointers) you can use reference (*d-reference*) instead of pointer (*d-pointer*) in case of [PIMPL idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Handle_Body#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29).

I'm trying to understand if there are any serious issues with this implementation and what are the pros and cons.

**Pros:**

- Shorter syntax because of usage of "." instead of "->".
- ...

**Cons:**

- What if the *new ObjectPivate()* fails and *new* doesn't throw (e.g.: *new(std::nothrow)* or custom *new*) and returns *nullptr* instead? You need to implement additional stuff to check if the referance is valid. In case of pointer you just use:

```
if (m_Private)
  m_Private->Foo();
```

- In rare case of multiple constructors for the *Object* with complex initialisation logic the solution could be not applicable. [© JamesKanze]
- It fills more natural to use pointer for memory management. [© JamesKanze]
- Some additional implementation details needs to be considered (use of *swap()*) to ensure the exception-safety (e.g. implementation of assignment operator) [© Matt Yang]
- ...

**Here the sample code for illustration:**

```
// Header file

class ObjectPrivate;

class Object
{
public:
 Object();
 virtual ~Object();

 virtual void Foo();

 private:
   ObjectPrivate&  m_Private;
};

// Cpp file

class ObjectPrivate
{
public:
  void Boo() { std::cout << "boo" << std::endl; }
};

Object::Object() :
m_Private(* new ObjectPrivate())
{
}

Object::~Object()
{
  delete &m_Private;
}

void Object::Foo()
{
  m_Private.Boo();
}
```

Comment: If `new ObjectPivate()` fails, I think you should find a way to `throw`. No point in having an implementation-less pimpl.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm not sure what he means by "fails".  `new ObjectPrivate` calls `operator new` (which throws a `bad_alloc` if it fails), and a constructor (which can only report failure with by throwing an exception).

Comment: @JamesKanze Right. I was addressing OP's **Cons** section, but I guess that scenario would only be possible with `new (std::nothrow)`.

Answer (score 6):

It's really just a matter of style.  I tend to not use
references in classes to begin with, so using a pointer in the
compilation firewall just seems more natural.  But there's
usually no real advantage one way or the other: the `new` can
*only* fail by means of an exception.

The one case where you might favor the pointer is when the
object has a lot of different constructors, some of which need
preliminary calculations before calling the `new`.  In this
case, you can initialize the pointer with `NULL`, and then call
a common initialization routine.  I think such cases are rare,
however.  (I've encountered it once, that I can recall.)

EDIT:

Just another style consideration: a lot of people don't like something like `delete &something;`, which is needed if you use references rather than pointers.  Again, it just seems more natural (to me, at least), that objects managing memory use pointers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not convenient to write exception-safe code I think.

The first version of `Object::operator=(Object const&)` might be:

```
Object& operator=(Object const& other)
{
    ObjectPrivate *p = &m_Private;
    m_Private = other.m_Private;        // Dangerous sometimes
    delete *p;
}
```

It's dangerous if `ObjectPrivate::operator=(ObjectPrivate const&)` throws exception. Then what about using a temporary variable? Aha, no way. `operator=()` has to be invoked if you want change m_Private.

So, `void ObjectPrivate::swap(ObjectPrivate&) noexcept` can act as our savior.

```
Object& operator=(Object const& other)
{
    ObjectPrivate *tmp = new ObjectPrivate(other.m_Private);
    m_Private.swap(*tmp);                // Well, no exception.
    delete tmp;
}
```

Then consider the implementation of `void ObjectPrivate::swap(ObjectPrivate&) noexcept`. Let's assume that ObjectPrivate might contain a class instance without `swap() noexcept` or `operator=() noexcept`. I think it's hard.

Alright then, this assumption is too strict and not correct sometimes. Even so, it's not necessary for ObjectPrivate to provide `swap() noexcept` in most cases, because it's usually a helper structure to centralize data.

By contrast, pointer can save a lot of brain cells.

```
Object& operator=(Object const& other)
{
    ObjectPrivate *tmp = new ObjectPrivate(*other.p_Private);
    delete p_Private;
    p_Private = tmp;        // noexcept ensured
}
```

It's much more elegant if smart pointers are used.

```
Object& operator=(Object const& other)
{
    p_Private.reset(new ObjectPrivate(*other.p_Private));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some quick and obvious additions:

**Pro**

- The reference must not be `0`.
- The reference may not be assigned another instance.
- Class responsibilities/implementation are simpler due to fewer variables.
- The compiler could make some optimizations.

**Con**

- The reference may not be assigned another instance.
- The reference will be too restrictive for some cases.